# Can I deeplink for ahead of scheduled rides?

Tags: uber-api

When I offer a deeplink into the Uber app: can a set a pick-up time in the future? E.g. two hours from now?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for expressing your interest in such a feature! We currently don't have a deeplink parameter to set up scheduled rides. However, we captured your interest and will consider it for future improvements.

Consider [subscribing to our blog post for API updates](https://medium.com/uber-developers). Thanks!